# Poisson model between mean difference and contingency table?

Tags: regression, modeling, poisson-regression, clinical-trials

I want to plan a study where I want to correlate change in mean parameters and results of discrete events (a 2x2 contingency table).

For every site of my study I'll have two group of patients, one receiving drug A and one receiving drug B. I'll measure change in mean of parameter C after follow-up and I'll be recording adverse events during follow-up.

So my data will be something like this:

site - mean change - drug - adverse event - sample size

1 - 5.2 - A - 20 - 200

1 - 4.2 - B - 40 - 500

2 - 5.3 - A - 10 - 150

how can I use a Poisson regression with R in order to investigate this relationship? It's correct to use reduction in incidence rates and mean difference only on group A drug patients?

Comment: I am not sure how the variables line-up with the headings. If I read it right site 1 had a mean change of 5.2, all subjects took drug A, there were 20 adverse events, and the number of subjects is 200.  If this is right for the first line what is the change of 5.2 a change from and what are you measuring?  If there are 20 adverse events is that 1 per subject so that 20 also is the number of subjects or can a subject have more than 1 adverse events?

Comment: Dear Michael, I forgot to say that the data I proposed are only illustrative and not corresponding to a true example but only for explaining my situation, subjects can have though more than 1 event